# time complexity of loops for programming contests problems

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Which has greater time complexity, a `for` loop or a `while` loop?
Can anyone give me a chart to compare the time complexity of different loops?
If possible suggest good references to learn about time complexity.

Comment: Time complexity depends on the number of iterations in a loop and the number of loops. Not on the type of loop.

Comment: Your question is ill-defined. The time complexity of a loop depends on the number of iterations. The type (for vs while) is irrelevant.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal which loop to use if i know the number of iterations ??\

Comment: @Victor how to decide then which loop you should use in order to minimise time if i already know the number of iterations.

Answer (score 3):

Barring a few technicalities, a while loop and a for loop are isomorphic:

```
for (a; b; c) { 
    body; 
}
```

can be turned into:

```
a;
while (b) {
   body;
   c;
}
```

As such, there's no difference in computational complexity between the two.

As to choosing between the two: the usual rule of thumb is to use a `for` loop if at least two of the three clauses are meaningful for that loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing the exact same thing with them, they should be pretty much exactly the same.  For instance:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10)
    i++;
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++);
```

should have pretty much exactly the same time complexity, since they are doing the exact same thing.

The only thing that changes the time complexity would be what is inside of the loop.  But there's really no reason to favor `for` over `while` other than it adds a convenient way to declare and iterate a variable.